# Using custom UITableViewCell's accessory view to show two items

Tags: ipad, uitableview, accessoryview

I've been looking for this for a while, but haven't found an answer (blame poor googling skills).  I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class which, currently, consists of a custom `UISwitch` and a `UILabel`.  I want to add a button that's only visible (And active) when the switch is set to "Yes".  Right now I add the switch to the `accessoryView`, and leave it.  However, the accessory view doesn't really have subviews, as far as I can tell, so here's my question:

Should I just create a `UIView` that has a button and a switch, size it to fit the cell's accessory view (or will it auto-size itself?), and put that in as the cell's accessory view?  And is this typically the way that it's gone about?

Or is there a solution that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
UIButton* btdel = [[UIButton alloc] init]; 
btdel.tag = indexPath.row; 
//[btdel setTitle:@"Delete Event" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btdel setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonRemove.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btdel addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// bt.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 95,24); 
btdel.frame = CGRectMake(110, 0, 30,30); 
[headerView addSubview:btdel];
[btdel release];

UIButton* bt = [[UIButton alloc] init]; 
bt.tag = indexPath.row;  
[bt setTitle:@"Select a Dress" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findDress.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(showDresses:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

bt.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat ) 13];

// bt.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 95,24); 
bt.frame = CGRectMake(0, 3, 95,24);

[headerView addSubview:bt];
cell.accessoryView = headerView;
```